# Why are these two If-statements not the same?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I just started learning Javascript. Currently I'm taking an online course and I just ran into my first problem I do not understand.

I want to check how many guesses I still have in a Hangman game:

```js
const Hangman = function(word, remainingGuesses) {
  this.word = word.toLowerCase().split('')
  this.remainingGuesses = remainingGuesses
  this.guessedLetters = []
}

Hangman.prototype.getPuzzle = function() {
  let puzzle = ''

  this.word.forEach((letter) => {
    if (this.guessedLetters.includes(letter) || letter === ' ') {
      puzzle += letter
    } else {
      puzzle += '*'
    }
  })

  return puzzle
}
```

the correct `if` statement in the video is this:

```js
Hangman.prototype.makeGuess = function(guess) {

  const isUnique = !this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)
  const isBadGuess = !this.word.includes(guess)

  if (isUnique) {
    this.guessedLetters.push(guess)
  }

  if (isUnique && isBadGuess) {
    this.remainingGuesses--
  }
}
```

But this is below here how I wrote the `if` statement:

```js
Hangman.prototype.makeGuess = function(guess) {


  if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)) {
    this.guessedLetters.push(guess)
  }

  if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess) && !this.word.includes(guess)) {
    this.remainingGuesses--
  }
}
```

The remaining guesses are not calculating correctly, if I do the `if` statements the second way. Can you please tell me what is the difference?

Comment: In your code, in the 2nd `if` you call `includes()`. However, the first `if` may have pushed the letter so the result of the `includes()` call is different. In the working code, the checks are done before the array is modified.

Comment: @epascarello No, why?

Comment: Hi @P.Walko - this JS visualizer can be really helpful if you want to see the steps in your code execution. It will help you better understand what is going on on each step and hopefully - help you to debug the program. https://tylermcginnis.com/javascript-visualizer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)) {
    this.guessedLetters.push(guess)
}
```

If `this.guessedLetter` didn't include `guess`, it's added to the list (with `push`).

```
if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)
```

You just modified `this.guessedLetters`. So now, when you check again, `guess` is always there, so this condition is never true.

Answer (score 2):

In your last example you change the `guessedLetters` array by using `push()` method.
This may lead to a different result of the `includes()` method of that same array.

Try to undestate it yourself if you translate it in 'normal' English:

1. If guess is not in guesses list, add it to guesses list.
2. If guess is not in guesses list and not in word list, decrease remaining guesses

This says. If guess is not in guess, you will add it and the second condition will automatically be false, because you just added guess to the guesses list and so it is not NOT on the guesses list.

You can do it like this instead

```
if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)) {
    this.guessedLetters.push(guess)

    if (!this.word.includes(guess)) {
       this.remainingGuesses--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, try to analyze the flow of a case where the `guessedLetters` **doesn't contain** the `guess`:

```
// if the guessedLetters doesn't contain guess ...
if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)) {
    // ... then you add it
    this.guessedLetters.push(guess)
}

// and it already contains guess so the first clause of the if
// is always false
if (!this.guessedLetters.includes(guess) && !this.word.includes(guess)) {
    this.remainingGuesses--
}
```

In the original, they first compute both flags `isUnique` and `isBadGuess` and only then they modify `guessedLetters` and `remainingGuesses`. The `if` clause checks the unmodified `guessedLetters` collection then.